# How to understand "trainspotters who enjoy a nice game of chess while indexing their stamp collection"

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

From a [article](https://html5forwebdesigners.com/design/#error_handling) which introduces HTML5:

> Error handling might not be of much interest to web designers, especially if we are writing valid, well-formed documents to begin with, but it’s very important for browser makers. Whereas previous markup specifications were written for authors, HTML5 is written for authors and implementers. Bear that in mind when perusing the specification. It explains why the HTML5 specification is so big and why it seems to have been written with a level of detail normally reserved for **trainspotters who enjoy a nice game of chess while indexing their stamp collection**.

So, what is meaning of "trainspotters who enjoy a nice game of chess while indexing their stamp collection" in the context?

Comment: People who are (obsessively) engaged in multiple activities simultaneously each one of which requires great attention to detail. This is a form of exaggeration to make the point that the spec is very detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trainspotting, Playing chess, and Stamp Collecting are (stereotypically!) nerdy activities undertaken by people who enjoy obsessive attention to details and possibly don't interact very well in normal social situations. The implication here is that the authors of the spec are themselves obsessive and possibly poor at social interaction.

Note that leveraging stereotypes like this is harsh and arguably unfair against both the target (html 5 authors) and people who participate in the hobbies in question. Such language is OK for adding a little bit of sensationalism to your web blog, but should be avoided in more professional contexts!

Answer (score 2):

Each of the 3 activities (trainspotting, chess playing, and stamp collecting) are thought to require an obsessive attention to detail. So when all 3 activities are combined, the implication is that the attention to detail is excessive and "over the top".